# CSRF Changes for href

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, csrf

I want to know what changes need to be made in below VF code to manage CSRF changes-

```
   <a href='/apex/{!if(pd.programType == "Partner Professional Services" || pd.programType == "Solution Provider" || pd.programType == "Service Provider" || pd.programType == "Technology Alliance Partner" || pd.programType == "Corporate Reseller" || pd.programType == "Distributor" || pd.programType == "Global System Integrator/Outsourcer" || pd.programType == "Training Center" || pd.programType == "VMware Partner Network","PCHome?name="+pd.landingPageName+"&language="+pd.prefferedLanguage,"page?name=home&program="+pd.programType+"&language="+pd.prefferedLanguage)}' target="_self">{!pd.programName}{!$Label.PC_Level}  {!$Label.PC_HomePage}</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you use <apex:outputlink> or <apex:commandlink>

Comment: I am trying to use  outputlink but receiving below error. 
The element type "apex:outputLink" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:outputLink>"

Comment: Sample output link used by me. 
<apex:outputLink value="'/apex/{!if(pd.programType == "Partner Professional Services" || pd.programType == "VMware Partner Network","PCHome?name="+pd.landingPageName+"&language="+pd.prefferedLanguage,"page?name=home&program="+pd.programType+"&language="+pd.prefferedLanguage)}'" target="_self">  test</apex:outputlink>